# Adding robots.txt plugin to django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to include a robots.txt in my django project and am running into quite a bit of trouble. I'm at the point of throwing my hands up and screaming.  :)

I have been trying to use this plugin https://github.com/nkuttler/django-robots-txt and have followed all the steps. But I keep receiving 502 bad gateways. So there is something I am missing, but I have no idea what.

I have installed the plugin via pip

```
pip install django-robots-txt
```

Gone to my root url.py and added

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from robots_txt.views import RobotsTextView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^robots.txt$', RobotsTextView.as_view())
)
```

and tried adding it to my installed Apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'robots_txt'
)
```

What am I missing? Please save me from this 502.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you reach another page of your Django project? It looks like the error is coming from the server itself. Not from Django.

Comment: Just to check: are you running nginx and uWSGI, with nginx set up to forward everything to uWSGI? Are you getting a 502 if you go to http://yourserver/ or just http://yourserver/robots.txt (you might want to give more details re: your nginx setup)

Comment: @Dunatotatos After installing that plugin I cannot reach anything on the site. Before I did the pip install I could.

Comment: @Foon I know this is directly connected to the plugin I installed and not with Nginx. This happened directly after I installed the plugin through pip.

Comment: If you're getting a 502 then that is coming from nginx. If the request was being routed to your wsgi app then you'd receive a 404 if the URL wasn't being recognized. Can you show us your nginx config?

Comment: I will put a screenshot in the question, but I have changed data so I'm not revealing the server and such